# What does the stop overlay means on a pinned data tip?

Tags: visual-studio

When looking at member in *Locals*, the wrench means a property and the heart means `internal`:

[image]

But when pinned, the heart is replaced by a stop sign:

[image]

**Question:**

What does the stop sign means?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Visual Studio Image Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/ux-guidelines/images-and-icons-for-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) turned out to be useful:

[image]

Not sure why it sees it as sealed but at least I have an answer to the question.